# Give an example of a set which has exactly 3 limit points and the set is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, set-theory

So the question is,

> Give an example of a set of real numbers which has exactly 3 limit points and the set is closed.

I have been trying to solve it by myself, and I know one potential set can be $A$, such that,
$A = \{k + \frac{1}{n}\ : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$
Where $K$ is the limit point of $A$.

The problem with this set is, this set is not closed, by the definition of a closed set, the set also need to contain it's limit points, but $k \notin A$

Comment: Hint:  Look at the closure of that set,  which just adds $k$.    Now do it 3 times

Comment: What do you mean by closure of a set? Sorry I am very new in real analysis...

Comment: The closure of a set is the smallest closed set it is a subset of,  you get it by adding all the limit points

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A(k)=\{k+\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup \{k\}$, then $A(k)$ is closed and has one limit point, ie $k$. Now take $A(0)\cup A(1) \cup A(2)$. which is a finite union of closed sets, and hence closed. It contains three limit points, ie 0, 1, and 2, and it's easy to check it doesn't contain any others.

Comment: I don't know why I did not think about adding k into the set in this way.... This is simple but genius. Thank you!